# Tracking Down Likely Permissions Issue

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Job with a single step, execute a stored procedure.

This stored procedure is fairly simple:

1. Initialize date variable.
2. Truncate table.
3. Create Temp Table.
4. Insert into Temp table from output of another Stored Procedure that is passed the date variable from step 1.
5. Insert into table from step 2 with data in Temp Table.
6. Drop Temp Table.

Everything runs fine, except for a small portion of the stored procedure called in step 4. This stored procedure includes a scalar function that returns a decimal (28,2). When I run this stored procedure individually myself, everything is great, function returns expected values. When I run the stored procedure in the job myself, everything is great, all outputs normal.

However, when the job runs on its scheduled basis, the function in question always returns 0 (not the expected output). I've adjusted the jobs "Run As" to myself, which corrects the issue, but I would love to figure out what is the problem with the default user that prevents the scalar function from returning the expected results.

Unfortunately I'm not even sure where to begin with something like this. Any points in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: First - stop assuming. A permissions error will throw **an error** which your job would see (if the error was not eaten somehow). More likely is an assumption in the code that involves an interpretation of this date based on a runtime setting (like language or datefirst). So look at that parameter and how it is populated and how it is used.

Comment: Also, reverse your tests, and run the stored procedure manually using impersonation, so EXECUTE AS and then choose the user that you want the agent job to run as.  Then you can debug the script directly.